# Trying to run two SSL vhosts on two ports on the same server (Apache 2.4.6 on Centos)

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, centos-7

I want to run two sites on the same server, both SSL, one on port 443, one on port 4444.

I have edited the `vhosts-ssl.conf` to have:

```
Listen <IP address>:443 https
Listen <IP address>:4444 https
```

at the top.

I have copied the existing, working `<VirtualHost *:443>` directive to a second one, exactly the same except that it has `<VirtualHost *:4444>` and a different `DocumentRoot` (which exists and is readable). They have the same `ServerName`. I have rebooted Apache.

When I try to connect to `https://servername<no port>` it works fine and shows me the *:443 site. When I try to connect to `https://servername:4444` the browser responds with `servername unexpectedly closed the connection`.

`netstat` shows httpd as listening on that port.

Comment: Have you checked if the server has a firewall setup and is allowing traffic to port `4444`? You can easily check from the command line by running `iptables -L -n` and seeing what the output is. If a firewall is running, then you need to allow `4444` to be reached. Another simple test is to login to the server and run this Curl command: `curl -ILk https://localhost:4444` and see what the output is. That Curl command shows headers (`I`), tells it to follow redirects (`L`) and then ignore HTTPS cert errors (`k`).

Comment: Thanks. You were right about it not accepting incoming requests on that port. Still not solved though! I've updated `iptables` but it's still not working.